# Set Image in visible UITableviewCell after async download

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, alamofire

I have a tableView with dynamic cells. Each cell has got an imageView and a textLabel. I'm working with Alamofire & AlamofireImage by the way.
My problem is that the first cells (which you see if view did appear) don't show the images. But if i scroll down i see the images of the other cells. And if scroll up again the images of the first cells appear too.

1. First of all i download user data in the viewDidLoad method. After this is done I update the tableview with tableView.reloadData().

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       MYRequest_getUsers(//...
           ,
           success: {response -> Void in
               self.users = response
               dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
                   self.tableView.reloadData()
               })
           },
           failure: {NSError -> Void in
           debugPrint(NSError)
       })
   }
   ```
2. TableView counts the users and reloads itself.

   ```
   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return users?.count ?? 0
   }
   ```
3. In tableView_cellForRowAtIndexPath method i fill the cells with user data.

   ```
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(self.identifier) as! UserCell

   cell.userNameLabel.tag = indexPath.row

   let rowData: User = self.users?[cell.userNameLabel.tag] as User!

   cell.userNameLabel.text = rowData.getName()

   let avatarURL = rowData.getAvatarURL() ?? ""

   cell.userImageView.af_setImageWithURL(imgURL, placeholderImage: placeholderImage)

   return cell
   ```

My idea was that after user data was loaded, the tableView begin to draw itself and place the name (because it is already in userData). But the image is downloaded (i suppose) asynchronously, so that they come from the backend after some delay and tableView is already drawn. After scrolling up and down i see them.

I want to open the screen and without scrolling up and down. Tableview should set automatically the images after they were loaded. So i thought to make a callback and use instead of

```
    cell.userImageView.af_setImageWithURL(imgURL, placeholderImage: placeholderImage)
```

this

```
    Alamofire.request(.GET, avatarURL)
        .responseImage { response in
            cell.userImageView.image = response.2.value
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                tableView.setNeedsLayout()
            })
    }
```

But nothing changes... I've tried a lot and looked similar problems but can't solve it... I hope you can give me some hints or much better a solution! :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Having the same issue with the image not being set – did you manage to find a workaround?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would like to give you a direction by posting the steps (best practice to follow in such case):

**Step 1 :** Fetch images in background as soon as you have image URLs available from server. I prefer doing this on operation queue where I download multiple images concurrently. You can write a helper class which takes a completion block and implement `NSOperation`/`NSOperationQueue`.

**Step 2 :** While images are being downloaded, for the eyes of users, put a loading overlay on image view. You can do this in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

**Step 3 :** Once images are available, cache them in file system. This is to avoid any scrolling abrupt behaviour.

**Step 4 :** Once images are available, call the completion block.

**Step 5 :**  In completion block, reload your table on main thread. Ensure your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` first check the image in cache, if present use it, if not present show loading overlay if image fetch is on flight. If image is not available in cache and download is also not going on, show some default image.

Answer (score 2):

This question is couple of years old, but maybe this answer can be useful to someone else with a similar problem, like me before to find the right solution.

Since the images are loaded asynchronously, we have to force a cell update when the download is finished if we didn't provide a fixed height for the UIIMageView. This because cell updating (i.e. AutoLayout Constraints recalculation) is done automatically only after `cellForRowAt` method, that is called when a cell is displayed for the first time, or when the table is scrolled to show other cells. In both cases probably the images are not yet downloaded by the `af_setImage()` method, so nothing but the placeholder will be displayed as their sizes are unknown for the moment.

To force a cell update we need to use `beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates()` methods, putting them inside the completion handler of `.af_setImage()`. This way, every time the downloading is completed, the cell will be updated.

But, to avoid a loop, before to call `beginUpdates()`/`endUpdates()` we have to check if we have already update the cell before, because by calling these methods, the `cellForRowAt` method is called again and consequently the `af_setImage()` and its completion closure with `beginUpdates()`/`endUpdates()` inside it).

This means that we have to update the cell only when the download is just finished, and not when the imaged is cashed (because, if it is cashed, it means that we have already updated the cell). This can be accomplished by checking the response of the completion handler: if it is not nil, the image was just downoladed, if it is nil, the image was cashed.

As a side benefit the cell height will be automagically adjusted (remember to put         `tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 400` and `tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension` in your `viewDidLoad()` method)

Finally, here it is the code:

```swift
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // Dequeue your cell
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "YourCustomCellIdentifier") as! YourCustomTableViewCell

        // get picture url from the data array
        let pictureUrl = self.yourCellsData[indexPath.row].pictureUrl

        // async download
        cell.pictureView.af_setImage(
                withURL:  URL(string: pictureUrl)!,
                placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "YourPlaceholder.png"),
                filter: nil,
                imageTransition: UIImageView.ImageTransition.crossDissolve(0.5),
                runImageTransitionIfCached: false) {
                    // Completion closure
                    response in
                        if response.response != nil {
                            // Force the cell update
                            self.tableView.beginUpdates()
                            self.tableView.endUpdates()
                        }
                }

        return cell
        }
```

That's all folks! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Few things to achieve this.

- call data download in viewwillappear and not in viewdidload.

  - in viewdidload, hide the tableview.
  - in viewdidAppear: check the data has downloaded and if so then call 
    [tableview reloaddata] method.